# Constrain does not take effect when eager loading in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have this function to get the results from joining relationships. However, the constraints don't seem to be taking effect. If I comment out the constraints, it still it gives the same result set as the uncommented constraints.

```
public function singleCategory($type, $category)
{
    $track = TrackType::with(['tracks.subgenres'], function($query, $category) {
        $query->where('name','=', $category);
    })->where('name', '=', $type)->get();

    dd($track->toArray());
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraining closure is only passed one parameter: `$query`. The other parameter you're trying to access (`$category`) needs to be made available via the `use` keyword:

```
public function singleCategory($type, $category)
{
    $track = TrackType::with(['tracks.subgenres'], function($query) use ($category) {
        $query->where('name', '=', $category);
    })->where('name', '=', $type)->get();

    dd($track->toArray());
}
```

### Edit

The above will not affect the TrackTypes that are returned, it will only limit the related subgenres that are eager loaded. Based on the comments, it seems as if you are trying to limit the TrackTypes returned to those that contain a certain subgenre. In this case, you need to use the `whereHas` method:

```
public function singleCategory($type, $category)
{
    $track = TrackType::with('tracks.subgenres')
        ->whereHas('tracks.subgenres', function($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('name', '=', $category);
        })
        ->where('name', '=', $type)
        ->get();

    dd($track->toArray());
}
```

### Edit 2

It sounds like your target result set is actually the tracks, and not the track types. If so, you probably want to start by querying the tracks, and add in your filter criteria from there (I don't know your exact model and relationship names, so adjust accordingly):

```
public function singleCategory($type, $category)
{
    $track = Track::with(['tracktype', 'subgenres'])
        ->whereHas('tracktype', function($query) use ($type) {
            $query->where('name', '=', $type);
        })
        ->whereHas('subgenres', function($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('name', '=', $category);
        })
        ->get();

    dd($track->toArray());
}
```

If you really are looking to start with the TrackType, then in addition to adding the `whereHas()` to find the TrackType, you need to add a `whereHas()` to filter down the Tracks that are eager loaded:

```
public function singleCategory($type, $category)
{
    $track = TrackType::with(['tracks' => function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->whereHas('subgenres', function($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('name', '=', $category);
            });
        }, 'tracks.subgenres'])
        ->whereHas('tracks.subgenres', function($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('name', '=', $category);
        })
        ->where('name', '=', $type)
        ->get();

    dd($track->toArray());
}
```

The first example is much cleaner. In plain English, the first example would sound like "get all tracks of a type and a subgenre". The second example would sound like "get the track type, but only if it has tracks in a certain subgenre; also, only load those tracks within that subgenre".

Comment: Thank you for the tip (Y) . but if i comment the $query->where('name','=', $category); Still its giving me the same result set ? Do you have Any idea why ?

Comment: @SithiraMunasinghe This functionality will only limit the subgenres that are eager loaded. It is not going to change the track types or the tracks that are loaded. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Yes that's my need . To limit subgeneres which are eager loading . For some reason its not limiting even with your snippet . Its Loads all tracks with Track type ignoring the constrain provided. 

i have setup my table structure like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-do-define-this-type-of-relationship?page=1#reply-124821) 
Please scroll down until you find migration snippets

Comment: insted of ['tracks.subgenres'], you need ['tracks.subgenres'] => and take a look at the whereHas()

Comment: @amirbar thanks for the pointing out the syntax error. how do you use whereHas. TrackType::whereHas(['track.subgenres']) ?

Comment: it all in the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships anyway something like: $track = TrackType::whereHas(['tracks.subgenres']=>function($query) use ($category) {
        $query->where('name','=', $category);
    })->where('name', '=', $type)->get();

Comment: i read the docs . whereHas throws an error . i have no idea  how to use it. Anyway thanks for the help @amirbar :) (Y) . This kinda works for me except the query gets all the Tracks associated with the given Tracktype .what i did was i checked if the subgeneres array is empty or not . i know its not nice but im out of options :( . Anyway thanks for your help (Y)

Comment: `whereHas` takes 2 parameters, a string and a callback.  An array will not work.

Comment: @SithiraMunasinghe I have updated the answer based on the comments

Comment: @patricus your new code worked from some extend . But still im getting unwanted tracks which don't belongs into the specified Sub-genre..

i have pasted my results . so that you can see what i mean 
[Results set](http://pastebin.com/ECpQyVfM)...
you can see that 2nd track is queried even though its not belongs to SubGenre i have specificed in the code . its just grabs all tracks belongs to type of Single

Comment: @SithiraMunasinghe I have updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Yep .. That's it. works like charm. Thank you so much @patricus . How ever i came up with my own solution . `code`$tracks = Subgenres::with(['tracks' => function ($query) { $query->where('type', 1); }])->where('name', 'ProgressiveTrans')->first();